# Testing with mockMvc for optional request header

Tags: spring, rest, mockmvc, request-headers

I have a rest controller with 2 path variables and 2 request headers (one required and one optional). I can test the rest api using postman to get data without or with providing the optional req header. 
But mockMvc fails when testing with optional req header.

I found mockmvc problem with optional path variable but could not find anything about how to test a optional request header.

my controller:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/{teacherId}/school/{schoolId}/test", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<? extends Object> getSupportDetails(@RequestHeader(userId) String userId,
@RequestHeader(value=classId, required=false) String classId,
@PathVariable String teacherId, @PathVariable String schoolId) {
            //some code
            }
```

My test class:

```
@Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

 @Before public void setUp() { this.mockMvc =
      MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.context).build(); }   

@Test
public void getSupportWithoutClassId() throws Exception {   this.mockMvc.perform(get("/{teacherId}/school/{schoolId}/test", "113", "105")
        .header("userId", "*")) 
        .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
        .andExpect(status().is(200));

    }
```

Expected result should be status 200.
but if I donot provide the optional header in header() I am getting an error:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Header value must not be null
```

But if I set the optional header too along with the required one, I am getting proper response.

How do I test this scenario with mockMvc?

Comment: Post the actual code (your code does not compile), and post the exact and complete exception stack trace.